# How to achieve more parallelism while reading data from oracle db using spark

Tags: apache-spark, ojdbc, azure-databricks

I am running spark on azure data-bricks. My requirement is I need to pull the data from oracle db and push the output it to files.

```
Spark verison - 2.4
Databricks cluster size - 8 nodes,8 cores for each node.
```

So to achieve more parallelism, I used hashing algorithm on partition column in oracle query.

```
example - mod(ora_hash(id), 64) as partition_key
```

Problem is, though I have 64 cores available in Data-bricks cluster, only 8 cores are running to pull the data from oracle.

Please find the attached screen shot for reference.

[image: executors tab]
[image: executor tab with task level]

following is the code -

```
     spark
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", jdbc_url)
      .option("dbtable",crmquery)
      .option("lowerBound", 0)
      .option("upperBound", 64)
      .option("partitionColumn", "partition_key")
      .option("numPartitions", 64)
      .option("Driver",driverClass)
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", pswd)
      .option("fetchsize",1000)
      .load()
      .write
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("escape","")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .csv(path)
```

Can someone help me , how to increase more connections to oracle DB while reading it? I can make use cores till 56.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hash your data before reading with Spark and I would say this is causing problems. Lower bound and upper bound lets Spark rerun your query adding a WHERE clause to read data into partition like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crmquery WHERE partition_key >= 0 and owner_id < 64
SELECT * FROM crmquery WHERE partition_key >= 64 and owner_id < 128
```

...

Since you hashed the data before, you don't have any data with partition_key >= 64

Specifying instead only partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound and numPartitions should lets you achieve what you want.
Also I think you'd better rely on [jdbc method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) instead of format with all that options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: as I am giving upperBound and numPartitions as 64, it should it create 64 querys like this?                          
SELECT * FROM crmquery WHERE partition_key >= 0 and owner_id < 1 
SELECT * FROM crmquery WHERE partition_key >= 1 and owner_id < 2    .... etc

Comment: It distribute data evenly across partitions based on the values of the partition key